# Change in twitter login

Tags: android, twitterkit, twitter-login

As we know, there have been changes in access to the twitter API referring to callbacks URLs.
So far, I have been using the identification callback with firebase, as I indicated here:

[image]

This has been working perfectly so far.

I read in the documentation that now you have to indicate the callback, according to android or iOS in the following way:

> twitterkit- : // if using Twitter Kit for iOS or
>   twittersdk: // if using Twitter Kit for Android.

My application is only developed for android.

I have tried all the possible variants, but I always get the following error:

**The client application failed validation: Not a valid callback URL format.**

The tested options have been:

```
twittersdk://pfa89MGYola62VIln ........ (MY_CONSUMER_KEY)

twittersdk://MY_APP-android.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler

twittersdk://https://MY_APP-android.firebaseapp.com/__/auth/handler
```

I have activated and deactivated the check "enable callback locking" ...

I've tried everything, I'm a little desperate

For another test, I tried to register the URL callback as if it were the iOS platform

```
twitterkit-MY_CONSUMER_KEY://
```

and it was accepted on the first attempt.

I do not mind losing the relationship with firebase, the truth is that I was not using it, but I have a serious problem if I can not connect with twitter again.

I appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I put it here in case it can be of help to someone.
The truth is that it is not well specified in the documentation, you have to take two steps.
First: activate the "enable callback locking" checkbox
Second: indicate the android sdk for twitter, WITHOUT CONSUMER KEY, unlike iOS users.

It would be like this:

[image]

I hope it helps

Comment: can you specify where one can find "enable callback locking". I keep reading that but in the dev console i do not see that.

Comment: For me, it was enough to just add "twittersdk://" into the callback URLs.